# Create range of ID without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands, sql-server-2017

Not sure if this or similar question is asked already but i could not find one.

The Requirement to create range of IDs while the Value is not changed. This schema can be used:

```
declare @mytable as table(ID int, Val int)

insert into @mytable values
(1,     1),
(2,     1),
(3,     1),
(4,     2),
(5,     2),
(6,     2),
(7,     2),
(8,     1),
(9,     1),
(10,    1),
(11,    4),
(12,    4),
(13,    4),
(14,    4),
(15,    4),
(16,    5);
```

And the expected result would be

```
StartID     EndID   Val
1           3       1
4           7       2
8           10      1
11          15      4
16          16      5
```

Now I can achieve this by running cursor and If n case the number of records will be millions, I think, cursor will be slower. I hope it can be written using some compound query but could not figure-out how.

So I need help in writing that kind of query and needless to mention yet, it is **not** a school/collage project/assignment.

Comment: Strange!! A down vote without any comment about what's wrong here?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? (2005 / 2016 / etc.)

Comment: It is SQL server 2017 express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  But the simplest method is the difference of row numbers:

```
select min(id) as startId, max(id) as endId, val
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by val order by id) as seqnum_v
      from @mytable t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_v), val
order by startId;
```

Comment: Did not noticed that it is a simpler solution and when the other solution failed due to some other issue(data problem), I realized that smaller query is easier to debug/fix :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) scenario where you're trying to group records together based on the change in `Val`.

This is using [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to determine when the `Val` changes, and assign the `island_nbr`.

**Answer:**

```
select min(b.ID) as StartID
, max(b.ID) as EndID
, max(b.Val) as Val
from (
    select a.ID
    , a.Val
    , sum(a.is_chng_flg) over (order by a.ID asc) as island_nbr
    from (
        select m.ID
        , m.Val
        , case lag(m.Val, 1, m.Val) over (order by m.ID asc) when m.Val then 0 else 1 end is_chng_flg
        from @mytable as m
        ) as a
    ) as b
group by b.island_nbr --forces the right records to show up
order by 1
```

Comment: This is what I needed.. Thanks

Comment: What is the lowest/oldest SQL Server version this query works with?

Comment: I believe that would be SQL Server 2012.